# Como obter o caminho atual de um script .sh?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, cross-platform

No sistemas baseados em Linux sempre que necessito uso o seguinte comando:

```
#!/bin/bash

BASEDIR=$(dirname "$0")

echo $BASEDIR
```

Todavia li em diferentes locais que `$(dirname "$0")` não é suportado pelos sistemas Mac OS X e sistemas baseados em BSD (aparentemente ambos baseados em Unix).

Via algumas alternativas, mas todas sempre tem uma critica, ou alguma menção falando que falha em algo.

O que eu preciso é saber se existe alguma maneira de pegar o diretório do script atual de maneira cross-platfom (unix-like)?

Outra coisa, eu gostaria de saber como obter tanto o caminho do diretório real quanto o caminho de um link simbólico.

> **Nota:** Não precisa ser com `bash`

Comment: Ah, tá, kkkkk, Vacilei na resposta

Comment: o `pwd` não serve pro teu caso?
http://devblog.drall.com.br/obter-o-caminho-real-de-um-link-simbolico/

Comment: @PabloVargas obrigado, sabaria me dizer se isto é cross? Todavia assim que instalar o BSD e o linux irei testar também. Obrigado por enquanto.

Comment: Não sei lhe dizer, sempre usei esses comandos só no Linux

Comment: `pwd` é padrão POSIX, isso significa que é altamente compatível não apenas nos sistemas operacionais baseados em UNIX (Linux, Android, iOS, OpenBSD, macOS, HP-UX, Solaris, ...), como também no Windows 10 através do Bash ou nas versões anteriores instalando o SUA(oficial da MS)/Cygwin

Answer (score 4):

Utilizando a linha de comando no Linux, é possível utilizando o comando shell pwd para obter o caminho(path) do diretório alvo.
No entanto, quando se executa este comando dentro de um diretório que é um link simbólico, este comando normalmente retornará o caminho para o link simbólico e não o diretório real apontado. Este comportamento está correto e é o esperado. No entanto, por vezes, precisamos obter o diretório real apontado. Para isto, basta:

```
$ pwd -P
```

(mostra o path do diretório real apontado pelo link simbólico quando dentro do diretório)

```
$ pwd
```

(mostra o path do link simbólico quando dentro do diretório)

Comment: Ótimo pablo, vou tentar instalar o freeBSD e o Debian em algumas maquinas virtuais e testar, obrigado por enquanto :D

Comment: +1, Um complemento legal seria colocar o BASEDIR=$(pwd) na resposta, pra usuários que não conhecem bem o shell saberem como capturar o valor (e mencionar sobre a necessidade ou não de aspas em volta do ="$(pwd)" )

Comment: @Bacco é que a minha resposta foi mais para apresentar o comando `pwd`, não sou muito conhecedor de bash, mas fique a vontade para por mais uma resposta com suas sugestões.

Answer (score 3):

É estranho que o `dirname` não esteja disponível no `BSD` e no `MacOS`, dado que é um simples programa em `C`, cujo código está em diversos repositórios.

Por exemplo: aqui [OpenSource Apple](http://opensource.apple.com//source/patch_cmds/patch_cmds-9/patch/dirname.c) 
e aqui [OpenBSD](http://ftp.stu.edu.tw/BSD/OpenBSD/src/usr.bin/dirname/). Basta compilar e usar.

De qualquer forma, talvez seja útil uma solução baseado no caminho relativo à posição de chamada, dado que permite localizar "sempre" o `script`:

Eis uma proposta para experimentar a ver se dá jeito:

script: `onde_estou.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR_RELATIVO="${0%/*}"

DIR_CHAMADA="${PWD}"

SCRIPT_PATH=$DIR_CHAMADA/$DIR_RELATIVO

echo "Desde a posição de chamada:"
echo "--> $DIR_RELATIVO"

echo "Posição de chamada:"
echo "-->$DIR_CHAMADA"

echo "Junção das duas:"
echo "--> $SCRIPT_PATH"

echo " Exemplo de aplicação"
echo "Listar o conteúdo do diretório onde está o script"
ls $SCRIPT_PATH
```

O script pode ser chamado de vários locais diferentes e dá sempre um caminho até lá. Infelizmente faz algumas curvas :).